# Mongodb append some value to a field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

I have documents within a collection which have following mandatory fields

```
{ "name": "xyz", "isDeleted": false }
```

Now, when I need to delete the document the document becomes

```
{ "name": "xyz[timestamp]", "isDeleted": true}
```

Can this be done in single query?

Edit: I am trying to implement soft delete. The field name is indexed and that's why unique. So after deleting a document I want to append '[timestamp]' after name of delted element so that a new document with the same name can be created if required.

Comment: There is not enough information here to answer the question. Can you provide more details about your use case?

Comment: MongoDB does  not have any operators that reference the existing value of a field in an update ( with the exception of `$inc` and the like ). The only way to do this is read the document, and use the existing value as it is read in a separate update statement.

Comment: Still not clear what you're asking. What do you mean by, "MongoDB does not have any operators that reference the existing value of a field in an update"

Comment: Jeffrey and @user3561036: Yes, I wanted to know that is it possible to read the document and use existing fields while update.

Comment: @VaibhavRaj So the answer is there. No it is not possible. I know this question has been asked many times in a similar form here. The only way to alter and "augment" information already present in a document is to read the document first.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.coll.find({}).forEach(function(mydoc){
   mydoc.name = mydoc.name.concat("[").concat(new date()).concat("]");
   mydoc.isDeleted = true;
   db.coll.save(mydoc)
})
```